When I update a Todo with the reminder value set to true, the checkbox is not being checked
So, I am learning Livewire. I made a small project (Todo) and plan to make it more advanced. The Todo title includes adding, updating, and deleting tasks, and I created my own custom data table. Now, I want to add a checkbox for reminders. If it is checked, a new field appears, allowing the user to select a date and time for the reminder. The issue is that when I update a Todo with the reminder value set to true, the checkbox is not being checked. The backend logic is working because the datetime field appears when the reminder value is true. Here is my code:
 <div x-data="{ isReminder: @entangle('isReminder') }">
            <div class="mt-3 transform transition-all"
                x-show="isReminder"
                x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100"
                x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-300"
                x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 scale-100"
                x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 scale-90">
                <x-label for="remiderDateTime" class="mb-1" value="{{ __('Reminder Date Time') }}" />
                <x-custom.datepicker></x-custom.datepicker>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="isReminder" x-model="isReminder" id="checked-checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 rounded" wire:model="isReminder">
                    <label for="checked-checkbox" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-gray-500">Reminder</label>
                </div>
                <x-button class="ms-4 bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-900">
                    {{ $isUpdating ? __('Update') : __('Submit') }}
                </x-button>
            </div>
        </div>

Todos.php
public $isReminder = false;

public function editTodo($id)
    {
        $todo = Todo::find($id);
        if ($todo) {
            $this->todoToUpdate = $todo->id;
            $this->title = $todo->title;
            $this->isReminder = $todo->isReminder;
            $this->remiderDateTime = $todo->remiderDateTime;
            $this->formTitle = 'Edit Todo';
            $this->isUpdating = true;
        }
    }


When / where do you call editTodo()? It reads the Todo data from the db but we don't know if isReminder is updated to true. x-model="isReminder" can be omitted

@TUPKAP here:
the thing is when i click edit the value of checkbox changes as I checked in inspect, but it is not actually showing the checked state. it is omitting the value because when isReminder value is 1 then the date field show.
    <button type="button"
            class="{{ $listItem->isCompleted == 1 ? 'show-class' : 'disable-class' }} mx-1 rounded p-1" wire:click="editTodo({{ $listItem->id }})"
            wire:loading.attr="disabled" {{ $listItem->isCompleted == 1 ? 'disabled' : '' }} x-on:click="{{ $scrollIntoViewJsSnippet }}">
    </button>


Unfortunately I can't understand how this part of code can help me to have a better idea of ​​the context. It is advisable to edit the question and insert all the additional code that contributes to composing a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
Keep in mind that as you have described the problem up to now everything works correctly for me, obviously I can't guess how the x-custom.datepicker component is made up. I also recommend you debug the $isReminder variable

@TUPKAP
this is the datepicker component:
`

`
this component don't have any issue. I just want to checked the checkbox when $isReminder is 1, I debug it and it gives me correct value.

It would have been better if you had modified the initial question as I indicated, inserting the code in the comments is inconvenient for the reader to manage.
From what I understand the datepicker is a Flowbite based component which as I think you know uses custom javascript code to work and this code can conflict with Livewire if not properly managed.

In my tests I replaced the datepicker with an <input type="text"> and as already said everything works as expected.
